# increment 0.1 to style with every ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs, animate.css

I'm trying to increment 0.1 to animation display for every ng-repeat. Is this possible with normal style or ng-style? I'm using AngularJS.

```
<tr ng-repeat="o in originalOrder | orderBy:'sort'" class="animated bounceIn" style="animation-delay: 0.1s;">
```

I would want the first one to be 0.1, second to be 0.2, third to be 0.3 and so on.

I'm using animate.css

Thanks

Comment: I'm using animate.css

Comment: I think you should look into `ngAnimate` module. `ng-repeat` has `ng-move`, and `ng-leave` events for these delays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="o in originalOrder | orderBy:'sort' track by $index" class="animated bounceIn" ng-style="{'animation-delay': (($index+1)/10)+'s'}">
```